# Tkinter theme is slow

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk, ttkthemes

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme) them in py tkinter program. My problem is that I make like 20 buttonst, it becomes very slow. I know that this is beacuse all the buttons have images. I alredy get a suggestion, that use OpenCV instead of tkinter to load images. But the images are loaded in the Tcl not in the Python file.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue?

UPDATE:

```
def draw(self):
   self['width'] = self.width
   self['height'] = self.height
   self['background'] = COLORS['GRAY3']
   
   s_btn_add_scene = ttk.Style()
   s_btn_add_scene.configure('scene.TButton', font=(FONT_NAME, self.font_size), padding=(0, 0))
   
   btn_add_scene = ttk.Button(self.viewport, text='Add Scene', style='scene.TButton')
   
   cf_scenes = CollapsingFrame(self.viewport, padding=10)
   btn_remove = ttk.Button(None, text='Remove', style='scene.TButton')
   btn_add = ttk.Button(None, text='+', style='scene.TButton', width=3)
   
   btn_add_scene.pack(anchor='nw', pady=10, padx=8)
   cf_scenes.pack(expand=True, fill='x', anchor='n')        

   for i in range(20):
       #TODO: remove   
       go = randint(0, 100)
       
       frame1 = ttk.Frame(cf_scenes, padding=10)
       
       for j in range(go):
           ttk.Label(frame1, text=f"GameEntity{j}").pack(anchor='w')
           
       cf_scenes.add(frame1, title=f"NewScene{i}", collapsed=True, widgets=[btn_remove, btn_add])
```

Comment: if it slow then you should rather use other framework - ie. `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython`

Comment: maybe problem is in code, not in themes. But you didn't show code, and we can't read in your mind. So we can't check it. BTW: as for me loading shouldn't be slow, but displaying can be slow.

Comment: I updated the question with my code that makes the drawing.
I also found an issue with the theme here: https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme/issues/11

Comment: You shouldn't recreate the buttons in every frame. Create them once and just change the attributes needed instead (like text).

Comment: I’m not recreating them. After I instantiate the class, I just call it’s draw method, than the root.mainloop()

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately tkinter themes are quite slow on Windows and macOS because reasons ... (on Linux there's not much problem with it, as that's the platform the toolkit was originally written for).

There's another theme I made ([sv-ttk](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme)) which is a bit better in terms of performance, but if you want something modern and snappy, you should look into alternative GUI toolkits.

The theme is also installable as a Python package: `pip install sv-ttk`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really did not expected it  What arra some good alternatives of tkinter if I want some good performing and decent looking GUI for Windows only?

Comment: Bitmap rendering is complicated, probably more than it needs to be. Most of that is due to how semi-transparency and reduced bit depth displays interact, at least as I understand it. I ought to look more at what is going on there, but I've been busy trying to finalize my contributions to the 9.0 beta.

Comment: @BálintCséfalvay I'd say it's Microsoft's newest GUI toolkit (they have a lot), however, they are probably not usable from Python, so maybe Qt.  I'm not really familiar with Windows in general.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in this area, but I believe the trend is to start using SVG graphics for themes rather than bitmapped images, for greater efficiency.  I see that the same guy has an svg theme at https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme-svg .  It might be worth trying that just to see if the slowness goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you explain how can it improve performance?

Comment: As I said, it's not really my area, I'm going by some comments I've seen in the Tcl chat.
Also this issue might throw some light on the subject: https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme/issues/11